# BT GPS - reading positions

Tags: linux, bluetooth, gps

In Linux;
How do I initialize a connection to a GPS, via Bluetooth?
... and read data from it?

This is not as trivial as opening a `/dev/ttyS0` serial port I found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial stages, to just see the flow of position data:

```
$ sudo -i
# bluetoothctl power on
Changing power on succeeded

# bluetoothctl agent on

# bluetoothctl scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 24:EE:9A:E2:9C:F7 Discovering: yes
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx RSSI: -42
Disconnected
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: no
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx RSSI: -73
```

hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the scan as you're seeing the MAC (xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx here)

```
 
# bluetoothctl trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Changing xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx trust succeeded

# bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 24:EE:9A:E2:9C:F7 Pairable: yes
[bluetooth]# trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Changing xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx trust succeeded

[bluetooth]# pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Attempting to pair with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: yes
Request PIN code
[agent] Enter PIN code: 0000
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx UUIDs: 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Paired: yes
Pairing successful
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx Connected: no

[bluetooth]# quit

# sudo rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 1 &
[1] 29050
Connected /dev/rfcomm0 to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx on channel 1
Press CTRL-C for hangup
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get a prompt (the output from `rfcomm ... &` obscured it)

```
# sudo miniterm  /dev/rfcomm0 4800
```

After the launch of miniterm there will first be an initial display of miniterm information (CTRL+T for menu, additional CTRL+H for help)

```
--- Miniterm on /dev/rfcomm0  4800,8,N,1 ---
--- Quit: Ctrl+] | Menu: Ctrl+T | Help: Ctrl+T followed by Ctrl+H ---
```

Shortly followed by a flow of textual data, assuming the previous steps has been done correctly / successfully.

```
$GPGGA,092750.000,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,1,8,1.03,61.7,M,55.2,M,,*76
$GPGSA,A,3,10,07,05,02,29,04,08,13,,,,,1.72,1.03,1.38*0A
$GPGSV,3,1,11,10,63,137,17,07,61,098,15,05,59,290,20,08,54,157,30*70
$GPGSV,3,2,11,02,39,223,19,13,28,070,17,26,23,252,,04,14,186,14*79
$GPGSV,3,3,11,29,09,301,24,16,09,020,,36,,,*76
$GPRMC,092750.000,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3372,W,0.02,31.66,280511,,,A*43
$GPGGA,092751.000,5321.6802,N,00630.3371,W,1,8,1.03,61.7,M,55.3,M,,*75
$GPGSA,A,3,10,07,05,02,29,04,08,13,,,,,1.72,1.03,1.38*0A
$GPGSV,3,1,11,10,63,137,17,07,61,098,15,05,59,290,20,08,54,157,30*70
$GPGSV,3,2,11,02,39,223,16,13,28,070,17,26,23,252,,04,14,186,15*77
$GPGSV,3,3,11,29,09,301,24,16,09,020,,36,,,*76
$GPRMC,092751.000,A,5321.6802,N,00630.3371,W,0.06,31.66,280511,,,A*45
```

*example data from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183*

**Notes:**
miniterm is in the `python3-serial` apt package
and bluetoothctl in `bluez`, wouldn't you already have the latter.

---

**Random links, to get further:**
https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez
https://geektechstuff.com/2020/06/01/python-and-bluetooth-part-1-scanning-for-devices-and-services-python/

Comment: This may also be of interest: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534819/bluetooth-is-soft-blocked-and-rfkill-unblock-doesnt-work i.e. `rfkill unblock bluetooth` 'should' work.

Comment: Still fighting with this; `ps -ax | grep rfcomm` may display a bunch of those, `sudo kill -9 $PID` where $PID is one of the listed ones, will remove them one by one. THEN you may retry the `rfcomm` lines above.